# Write iPhone requirements specification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, requirements

What do you use to draw iPhone ui and write iPhone requirements specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [balsamiq mockups](http://balsamiq.com/) to draw up the screens, then I write a up a page for each screen explaining behaviors

Comment: +1 I use that too, its quite good and doesn't give the impression that the app is already finished (avoids questions like "when can you deliver, tomorrow?")

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of stencils available out there for OmniGraffle and for Photoshop.  I've used Omnigraffle before to create images and drop them into a Word or Pages document.

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder generally to mock up a UI, and I typically write out spec informally in notes. However, if I were submitting these to other people (i.e., a contractor or subcontractor) I'd probably be using Pages or something similar to take my informal notes, and present something formal.